# typeahead.js - match query to start of results

Tags: typeahead.js

I am using Twitter typeahead.js for searching a list of names and the client wants the suggestions based on first names.

Is there an option to make Twitter typeahead.js match a search query with the start of each result, rather than anywhere within the string?

I can see a `beginsWithQuery` variable within the `_updateHint` function, however I don't know how to specify this as an option, or even if this relates to what I am trying to achieve.

The jQuery function which is calling typeahead in my project is:

```
$( 'input[name="s"]' )
  .typeahead( {
      name: 'search',
      remote: wp_typeahead.ajaxurl + '?action=ajax_search&fn=get_ajax_search&terms=%QUERY',
      template: [
        '<p><a href="{{url}}">{{value}}</a></p>',
    ].join(''),
      engine: Hogan
  } )
);
```

I can see the response from the `ajax_search` is in the format

```
[
  { "tokens" : [ "First","Last" ],
    "url" : "http://url/for/first-last/",
    "value" : "First Last" },
]
```

so I need to figure out how to filter this JSON to include only datums for which `token[0]` matches the search query.

EDIT: Additional notes about what I had to add to do to implement the `prefetch` solution work as per @jharding's anwser below.

This is a WordPress site, and the names the site is search are the titles of a custom post type of 'model'. I created a file called list-all-models.php which outputs an array of the model names in the required datum format.

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../../../wp-load.php'); // depends on where this file is

$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'model',
    'orderby' => 'title',           
    'order' => 'asc',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$models = get_posts($args);

$model_names = array();

foreach ($models as $i => $model) {
    $model_names[$i]['value']   = $model->post_title;
    $model_names[$i]['url']     = $model->guid;
    $model_names[$i]['tokens']  = explode(' ', $model->post_title);
}

header("Content-type: application/json");
die(json_encode($model_names));
?>
```

I then used the URL of this file as the url parameter in the `prefetch` option.

Now the search is working exactly as intended :)

Comment: Do you use remote data source?

Comment: @Tommi, yes. I just added the relevant code above. I think I need to use a filter to convert the response data into an array of datums which are only the first word of each value. But I don't know how to do that :(

Comment: I'd recommend you to do such filtering on server side. Pros: client browser does not perform heavy operations which can hang it; less data size to send via ajax => faster response; you don't need at all to find way to do it with typeahead.js (I took rapid view on its code and didn't found any way to change default filtering). If you really want to stick to client solution, you'll need to bind on your input `keydown` event, filter your preloaded array and bind filtered result as `local`. Though I'm not sure that typeahead designed to work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, typeahead.js doesn't do any sort of filtering on the data returned by `remote`. It's expected that the data returned by `remote` already contains valid suggestions for the given query.

It sounds like using `prefetch` may be a better option if you're expecting typeahead.js to handle matching suggestions to a query and since you have ~700 entries, you should see pretty solid performance. If you choose to go down that path, you'd want to do something like this:

```js
$('input[name="s"]').typeahead({
  name: 'search',
  prefetch: {
    url: '/path/to/json/file/that/returns/all/entries',
    filter: removeLastNameFromTokens
  },
  template: '<p><a href="{{url}}">{{value}}</a></p>',
  engine: Hogan
});

function removeLastNameFromTokens(data) {
  var datum, firstName;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    datum = data[i];
    datum.tokens.pop(); // assumes tokens looks like [First, Last]
  }

  return data;
}
```

Assuming `/path/to/json/file/that/returns/all/entries` points to a JSON file that contains an array of datums, `removeLastNameFromTokens` will iterate through each datum and remove the last name from `tokens`, leaving only the first name. This should result in the functionality you're looking for.

Another good strategy would be to use a combination of `prefetch` and `remote`. You could include the 100 or so most popular entries in the `prefetch` data and then rely on `remote` to backfill suggestions when `prefetch` can't produce enough suggestions.

Comment: The site has about 700 entries which the search is looking at, so I'm not sure that is a practical solution in my case, unless I can figure out how to add the tokens programmatically.

Comment: You might want to look into using the prefetch option. You could then use a filter to to transform the entries into the format I suggested. Otherwise there's no way to achieve the functionality you're asking about without forking typeahead.js.

Comment: Any pointers for how I would incorporate the `prefetch` option into the function above (I just added some code)? The docs state I need to define a URL to a JSON file of datums, however the list of entries is simply that names of all the posts in the database.

Comment: I now see that `remote` is for when `prefetch` is insufficent; [the docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#remote) state I need to use a filter to create the datums, but I don't know how to do that part.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how you'd use the prefetch filter to explicitly set the search tokens. Hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Definitely heading in the right direction... I've dug a bit deeper and I can see that the response from the ajax includes a `token` array for each datum. I have added this to my question above. So I think I need to match the first value of the `token` array to the search query. I think I am starting to see the benefit of `prefetch` here; if I query all 700 post titles and store that in a JSON file, I should be able to reference that. Also uncovered is that you are featured on the Typeahead docs, so it would appear I'm getting tips straight from the source: that deserves a green check.

Comment: Edited my answer again to so how you could use `filter` to remove last names from `tokens`.

Comment: Winner! I now have the search working exactly as the client requested. Thank you very much for your persistence with helping me bash this into shape.

Answer (score 0):

Apt solution would be:

```
 matcher: function (item) {
                        if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) == 0) {
                            return true;
                        }
```